# "SQL Case Then When" with accumulating the results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with three column, first column is number of months, the second is name of a company, and the third one is the number of complains of that company.
Some companies have no complains in some months, I want to generate a table, which one axis would be month axis and the other one would be the company name and the value of each cell of the table would be the number of complains.

Could you please help me with writing of this SQL Query?
This is my try with pivot (with Jason's help, but it won't work, and return null. P.S. Numb is float, and Complaint and Months are nvarchar)

```
select *
from 
(
  select Numb, Complaint, Months
  from Rezayat94
) src
pivot
(
  sum(numb)
  for months in ([1], [2], [3],[4],[5],[6], [7], [8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
) piv;
```

Thanks. :)

Comment: you want a pivot table

Comment: post some of your work....Have you tried this query? if yes than post your query here.

Comment: @Jasen I tried pivot but it seems words like week is a reserved word. Should I change my column names?

Comment: @SagarR I added it to the question

Comment: @yousefyegane : what error you are getting now?

Comment: It returns NULL for all of the returned cells.

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for months in ([1], [2], [3],[4],[5],[6], [7], [8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
```

This will work only if a value "1","2","3" is stored in your **Month** column. You specified that it is nvarchar datatype for your column. So, please replace ***[1],[2]...etc***  with your values from month column.

For example you have *Jan*,*Feb*... etc. So please use something like this

```
for months in ([Jan], [Feb],... , [Dec])
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Please inform if there is any problem.

```
select Numb, 
      Complaint,
      [1] AS Jan, 
      [2] as Feb, 
      [3] as Mar,
      [4] as Apr,
      [5] as May,
      [6] as Jun,
      [7] as Jul,
      [8] as Aug,
      [9] as Sep,
      [10] as Oct,
      [11] as Nov,
      [12] as Dec
from Rezayat94
pivot
(
  sum(numb)
  for months in ([1], [2], [3],[4],[5],[6], [7], [8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
) piv;
```

Comment: OK. But what about unicode characters? Should I change anything?

Comment: @yousefyegane I am not clear about your comment. Is your Months column is unicode characters? If that it will be same

Comment: I was using N'' in unicode characters, and I thought it might be needed in pivot too, but it worked, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use a pivot table.

```
DECLARE @COMPLAINTS TABLE ([MONTH] VARCHAR(3),COMPANY VARCHAR(1), NUMB FLOAT)
INSERT INTO @COMPLAINTS
VALUES 
('Jan','A',1),
('Feb','A',2),
('Mar','A',3),
('Apr','A',4),
('May','A',5),
('Jun','A',6),
('Jul','A',7),
('Aug','A',8),
('Sep','A',9),
('Oct','A',10),
('Nov','A',11),
('Dec','A',12),
('Jan','B',1),
('Feb','B',2),
('Mar','B',3),
('Apr','B',4),
('May','B',5),
('Jun','B',6),
('Jul','B',7),
('Aug','B',8),
('Sep','B',9),
('Oct','B',10),
('Nov','B',11),
('Dec','B',12),
('Jan','C',1),
--('Feb','C',2),
('Mar','C',3),
--('Apr','C',4),
('May','C',5),
--('Jun','C',6),
('Jul','C',7),
--('Aug','C',8),
('Sep','C',9),
--('Oct','C',10),
('Nov','C',11),
('Dec','C',12)

SELECT  COMPANY Company,
        sum(CASE WHEN [MONTH] = 'Jan' then numb else 0 end) as 'Jan',
        sum(CASE WHEN [MONTH] = 'Feb' then numb else 0 end) as 'Feb',
        sum(CASE WHEN [MONTH] = 'Mar' then numb else 0 end) as 'Mar',
        sum(CASE WHEN [MONTH] = 'Apr' then numb else 0 end) as 'Apr',   
        sum(CASE WHEN [MONTH] = 'May' then numb else 0 end) as 'May',
        sum(CASE WHEN [MONTH] = 'Jun' then numb else 0 end) as 'Jun',
        sum(CASE WHEN [MONTH] = 'Jul' then numb else 0 end) as 'Jul',
        sum(CASE WHEN [MONTH] = 'Aug' then numb else 0 end) as 'Aug',
        sum(CASE WHEN [MONTH] = 'Sep' then numb else 0 end) as 'Sep',
        sum(CASE WHEN [MONTH] = 'Oct' then numb else 0 end) as 'Oct',
        sum(CASE WHEN [MONTH] = 'Nov' then numb else 0 end) as 'Nov',
        sum(CASE WHEN [MONTH] = 'Dec' then numb else 0 end) as 'Dec'
FROM    @COMPLAINTS
GROUP   BY COMPANY
```

And the sum returns a 0 value for months where there are no complaints. The execution plan looks no more costly than a pivot (in this small test sample anyway)